# How to calculate the impulse response from the transmission function of an optical device?

Tags: impulse-response, transfer-function

Let $f(x,y)$ be the electric field in complex representation processed by an optical device described by a transmission function $t(x,y)$ such as:
$$
f'(x,y)=f(x,y)t(x,y)
$$

Where $f'$ is the output electric field.

How can I calculate the impulse response of the device? I don't understand how to determine a function $h(x,y)$ such as:
$$
f'(x,y) = f(x,y)*h(x,y)
$$

More specifically I'm working with a lens transmission function in the paraxial approximation:
$$
t(x,y)= P(x,y)\exp\left[-\frac{jk}{2f}(x^2+y^2)\right]
$$
where $P(x,y)$ is the pupil function of the lens (usually a $circ(x,y)$ function).

P.S.
I wonder if there is a general solution to the mathematical problem of finding a function $h$ for a given $t$ which satisfy $ft=f*h$ for a generic function $f$.

I've posted the same question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304444/ but I haven't received any answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the function $t(x,y)$ is an [optical transfer function (OTF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transfer_function) then your goal is not to find a function $h(x,y)$ such that the convolution with your input $f(x,y)$ equals the multiplication with $t(x,y)$. Convolution with the impulse response ([point spread function (PSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) in optics) happens in a different domain. The OTF is the Fourier transform of the PSD, and the equality

$$f'(x,y)=f(x,y)t(x,y)$$

corresponds to the equality

$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{f'(x,y)\}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{f(x,y)\}\star h(u,v)$$

where $h(u,v)$ is the impulse response (PSD) given by

$$h(u,v)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{t(x,y)\}$$

Comment: $t(x,y)$ is not the OTF but the "transmission function" defined above. $f$ is the field, not the fourier transform of the input.

Comment: @skdys: I'm definitely no expert in optics, but according to [this document](http://web.mit.edu/2.717/www/gbarb_COSI_3Doptics.pdf), "the impulse response is the Fourier transform of the thin transparency transmission function, ...".

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've discovered that "impulse response" is a term which is used with different meaning in optics. The real impulse response is the PSD as you mentioned above, however is not possible to calculate the impulse response of the single lens because it is not a linear system. You can calculate explicitly the PSD only of the complete system composed by the lens and the two propagations object-lens and lens-plane. As is described in Goodman "Introduction to Fourier Optics" in section 5.3. 
If you integrate this information in your answer I will accept that.